# How might Apache cause duplicate requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, nginx

I have two Rails apps that talk to one another. A few times a day, requests from app A show up in duplicate (or triplicate/quadruplicate) at app B. All outbound and inbound requests are logged. The logs show that app A is sending one outbound request and that app B receives that request twice or more during the same second.

App B sits behind Apache and an Amazon Elastic Load Balancer.

I am not sure where to look or even what questions to ask to hone in on what might be causing this issue. If you need more data, I would be happy to provide it.

Answer (score 2):

The retries are likely coming out of the Amazon Elastic Load Balancer or some network component (like a router, for example). I've seen similar behavior when using other load balancers (like Citrix NetScaler) as well.

Basically, the request gets an idle timeout at some level in the request chain. If that timeout doesn't send a proper HTTP 5xx status back to the client (for example it could just silently close the connection) then any components between the source of the timeout and the client can potentially decide to retry the request depending on how they are configured.

Tracking down which components cause the retries can be very challenging. My recommendation is to make sure your Rails applications always respond quickly to each other. If the requests can't complete quickly, consider perhaps a background/polling solution or a non-HTTP communication method (WebSockets for example).